# How to interchange the table cells using jquery ui using drag and drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to interchange the columns for the table on drag and drop.

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td class='1'>
   First
  </td>
  <td class='2'>
   Second
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class='3'>
   Third
  </td>
  <td class='4'>
   Fourth
  </td>
 </tr>
```

Now i can use the `draggable` function

```
 $(".1").draggable();
```

If i drag the `class='1'` `td` to `class='4'` `td` then 
both `td's` will interchange. How can i able to 
do this with `jqueryui`

Answer (score -1):

I think that you need the `sortable` functionality in JQueryUI

http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Example extracted from API: http://jsfiddle.net/D8Wgv/